# Autofocus in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, firefox

I'm trying to set the autofocus for username field, and my code works fine with all browsers except in FF.

I have added the small JavaScript code to override the issues one might encounter in older browsers, but it did not help me.

Code is the following:

```
<input id="login-username"
       class="inpt inpt-block"
       type="email"
       ng-focus="removeValidatorErrors()"
       required
       name="loginEmail"
       ng-model="login.userId"
       placeholder="hans.muster@company.com"
       autofocus>

<!--Autofocus fallback-->

<script>
   if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
     document.getElementById("login-username").focus();
   }
</script>
```

Not sure what exactly to do more, and to solve this issue.